# How to generate Exponential Random Variate in Java (e.g. inter-arrival of customers)

Tags: java, python, random, exponential

Hi I'm looking if there is any method that can generate Exponential Random Variate in Java. or any other way.

I used to have this method in Python, it's was really helpful.
random.expovariate(0.28)

Comment: Have you tried Apache Commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/index.html

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of numerical Java libraries http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#Java